# OpenManage returns "Hostname / IP address is Blank" when submitting valid hostname

Tags: centos, dell-openmanage

Just installed OpenManage 8 on a CentOS 6.5 system.  I access the login page with `https://1.2.3.4/1311` and that loads up without a problem.

I enter the system hostname (my.domain.tld), username and password, then click Submit.   OpenManage returns

```
Login failed.  
Hostname / IP address is Blank. 
Please enter a valid Hostname/IP address.
```

I've tried using the system's IP address, and verified that I am entering a valid username and password.

Coincidentally, I can click on Manage Web Server, and am able to log in using the same credentials (I'm not asked to enter a hostname on that login page).

Why is OpenManage complaining about a missing hostname when I am absolutely submitting a valid hostname on the login form?  I've restarted openmanage, and tried restarting the server also.  Same problem happens across multiple browsers and clients (hostname blank).

**edit**:  I just yum removed/installed `srvadmin-all`, still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unable to get logged in to the initial login screen, but I've found that after reinstalling `srvadmin-all` I now have access to manage DRAC configuration.

If I find a better solution for the question, I'll update this answer accordingly.